# Even if my android app destroy, com.google.android.gms drain battery

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, locationmanager, batterylevel

I am developing an android application that use google-play-services-lib. This app has a google map and use locationManager to determine user location. Next find google Places and track google directions for them. 
In my code i use

```
@Override
   protected void onDestroy(){
       super.onDestroy();
   }
```

But the com.google.android.gms services dont stop (even if wifi, 3G and gps turn off) and the battery drain. When i see battery usage of my device it has

CPU total usage 2min 3sec

CPU usage in background 2min 3sec

GPS 10 hours 30min.

In my code the only situations that require location update are

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = location.getLongitude();   
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));
        }
```

and

```
// Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 0, this);
```

But i thought that with super.destroy() that functions stop.

Can anyone help me with my problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to remove the updates. It will work in other thread
Try this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code but still  GPS icon with "Searching for GPS" is showing in the notifications.

Comment: Try to add a trace on the onDestroy method, may be it's not called yet.